# Dependency of attenuation in optic fibers on wavelength of light

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

I have read and heard that scattering, and attenuation in general increase with frequency.
However, in an experiment we did as a part of our course, we found that attenuation constant for light of wavelength 850nm, travelling through an optic fiber, was more than that for light of 650nm. Could someone please explain this?
(Also, I would appreciate if someone could elaborate in a simple way (or at least list), the different reasons for attenuation in an optic fiber, or provide a source with clear and detailed explanation of losses in optic fibers- None of the sources I have found yet were clear and organized enough for me)

Comment: Transitions in the fiber optic material.

Comment: Not an answer, but the frequency attenuation is mostly due to Rayleigh scattering (see e.g https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=170740&seqNum=6). 
Have you considered the possibility that your experiment was not performed correctly?